# Complemented subspaces in the James space

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $J$ be the James space. I have the following questions:

Question 1: Does every infinite-dimensional closed subspace of $J$ contain an infinite-dimensional closed subspace that is $C$-complemented in $J$? where the $C$ is the universal constant.

Question 2: Let $(u_{n})_{n}$ be a normalized skipped block basic sequence of the unit vector basis in $J$. Is the subspace spanned by $(u_{n})_{n}$  $C$-complemented in $J$? where the $C$ is the universal constant.

Obviously, if Question 2 is true, then Question 1 is true. I do not know what is the above universal constant $C$.

Thank you!

Comment: The answer to question 1 is **yes**.  See the comments after Remark 2.11 in http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4231 and Proposition 2.4 in http://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol36/GonzalezMartinez-AbejonSalas-Brown.html I do not know the answer to question 2.

Comment: I have not looked carefully yet, but it seems that the answer to question 2 might also be true. Check out section 2.d in *The James Forest* by Helga Fetter and Berta Gamboa de Buen. Most of it is on Google books.  https://books.google.com/books?id=GQJVVtDwx5wC&pg=PA43

Comment: Thanks, Ben.  Question 2 may follow from the book you mentioned. But I do not have this book and so I am not sure. Do you have the electronic version of this book?

Comment: No, I don't.  If it is important you could try to piece it together from what fragments are available on Google books.  I believe all of theorem 2.d.2 is visible there. By the way---out of curiosity, what are you studying about the James space?

Comment: I am studying about compact operators, strictly singular operators and strictly co-singular operators on the James space.

Comment: Cool.  I believe those classes all coincide for $J_p$ (the $p$th James space) when $1<p<\infty$.  This is because, as Laustsen showed, $\mathcal{K}(J_p)=\mathcal{E}(J_p)$ (where $\mathcal{K}\subset\mathcal{SS},\mathcal{SCS}\subset\mathcal{E}$ denote the compact, strictly singular, strictly cosingular, and inessential operators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both questions is **yes**.  Indeed, suppose $y_j=\sum_{n=p_j}^{q_j}\alpha_ne_n$ forms a block basic sequence in $J$ satisfying $p_{j+1}-q_j>1$ for all $j$.  It is shown in the proof of Theorem 2.d.2 of *The James Forest* that $[y_j]_{j=1}^\infty$ is complemented by a projection of norm $\leq 2\sqrt{2}$.  (It is also shown that if $(y_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ is seminormalized then it is equivalent to the $\ell_2$ basis.)